# Text Boxes Flow Off the Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I have complex pdf report I am trying to generate. My only problem is preventing text boxes from flowing off the page (as then they are not seen). It is okay if they flow on to the next page as long as they are seen.

I am using the text_box and move_down method in prawn for positioning.

Here is an example:

```
  def work_order_info(work_order, pdf)
    pdf.text_box '1/2/15', width: 80, at: [0, pdf.y], size: 9
    pdf.text_box '123', width: 50, at: [71, pdf.y], size: 9
    pdf.text_box 'Testing', width: 400, at: [150, pdf.y], size: 9
    pdf.text_box ''Testing, width: 75, at: [580, pdf.y], size: 9
    internal_comment(work_order, pdf) unless true
    work_logs(work_order, pdf) unless work_order.work_log.count > 0
    pdf.move_down 30 #If page end is reach doesn't flow to a new page
  end
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for me, I just check if the y position is negative and if it is start a new page. like so:

```
pdf.start_new_page if pdf.y - 10 < 0
```